# How can I find the shortest path in a maze?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, maze

My maze is a int array with two dimensions, `int maze[][]` containing `0,1,START(2),GOAL(3)`. I want to print the shortest path.

I have a function but it doesn't display the shortest path but one path to the end:

```
bool RenderThread::find_path(int x, int y)
{
    int maze_size=mmaze->size*2;

    if ( x < 0 || x > maze_size  || y < 0 || y > maze_size  ) return FALSE;

    if ( toSolve1->maze_data[y][x] == G ) return TRUE;

    if ( toSolve1->maze_data[y][x] != PATH && toSolve1->maze_data[y][x] != S ) return FALSE;

    toSolve1->setRed(y,x);


    if ( find_path(x, y - 1) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

    if ( find_path(x + 1, y) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

    if ( find_path(x, y + 1) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

    if ( find_path(x - 1, y) == TRUE ) return TRUE;

    toSolve1->setPath(y,x);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Here: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/ your algorithm is explained nicely, you can check there. Apart from that, if you want us to check you code for errors, you should include a maze to test the code on, and maybe tell us when it goes wrong. To find the error yourself you could print the maze to console etc. after each step to find where the error occurs.

Comment: For a start, replace `&&` with `||` in the fourth line of your function maybe? You should document the meaning of all the possible values that your matrix cells can take in your question : `S` is _start_? `G` is _goal_? `PATH` is a walkable position?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) algorithm.

[Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode):

```
function A*(start,goal)
    closedset := the empty set    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
    openset := {start}    // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node
    came_from := the empty map    // The map of navigated nodes.

    g_score[start] := 0    // Cost from start along best known path.
    // Estimated total cost from start to goal through y.
    f_score[start] := g_score[start] + heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

    while openset is not empty
        current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
        if current = goal
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)

        remove current from openset
        add current to closedset
        for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
            if neighbor in closedset
                continue
            tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)

            if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score <= g_score[neighbor] 
                came_from[neighbor] := current
                g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
                f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
                if neighbor not in openset
                    add neighbor to openset

    return failure

function reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node)
    if came_from[current_node] in set
        p := reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[current_node])
        return (p + current_node)
    else
        return current_node
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your maze is a grid, and walls are marked as inaccessible grid spaces, then A* Jump Point Search is currently the fastest optimal algorithm for this search space.